# Access attribute table of in-memory raster

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.3, spatial-analyst

I'd like to read from the attribute table of an intermediate raster generated by arcpy.sa.Combine:

```
combined = arcpy.sa.Combine(['raster1', 'raster2'])
arcpy.BuildRasterAttributeTable_management(combined)
data = [row for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(combined, ["VALUE", "COUNT"])]
```

The above code raises:
     `RuntimeError: 'in_table' is not a table or a featureclass`

Is there a way to access the RAT without saving the raster?

Comment: Try to create raster layer from it.

Answer (score 2):

Try setting `arcpy.env.workspace = 'in_memory'`, or the cursor will not know where to find the raster.

It could also be that `combined` is a raster object which the cursor cannot read. Try "saving" it to in_memory workspace:

```
combined.save(r"in_memory\outcombine2")
data = [row for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(r"in_memory\outcombine2", ["VALUE", "COUNT"])]
```

Comment: The second solution worked for me: I had to call `.save()` on the raster and then I could use `SearchCursor` on it like any other table.

This is odd, because you can print the variable containing the output of your raster tool (in your example, you could use `arcpy.AddMessage(f"Output raster={combined}"`) and it too will be a path to a raster. But you can't read its contents as a table.

In my case I was using `arcpy.sa.ExtractByAttributes`, so a lot of raster tools probably do this.